# Values Not Adding Up

Tags: python

Ok so here's my code:

```
tick = 1
week = 1
month = 1
year = 1

def new_week(week, tick):
    week = week + 1
    tick = tick + 1
    if tick == 4:
        new_month()
        tick = 1

new_week(week, tick)
print week, tick
new_week(week, tick)
print week, tick
```

No matter how many subsequent times I tell it to run the new_week() function and print the values for 'week' and 'tick', it always prints 1 for both... Why is it disregarding the 'week = week + 1' line and the same for 'tick'??

I'm running Python 2.7 btw

Comment: It's a scoping issue.

Comment: It matters, but it's not the immediate problem.

Comment: integers are immutable, and your function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The global names `week` and `tick` are being shadowed by the names of the function's arguments.

You need to remove these arguments (because they are unnecessary) and also declare `week` and `tick` as being global inside the function (this will allow you to modify their values):

```
tick = 1
week = 1
month = 1
year = 1

def new_week():
    global week, tick  # Declare that week and tick are global
    week = week + 1    # Modify the value of the global name week
    tick = tick + 1    # Modify the value of the global name tick
    if tick == 4:
        new_month()
        tick = 1

new_week()
print week, tick
new_week()
print week, tick
```

Output:

```
2 2
3 3
```

---

Note however that a lot of Python programmers consider functions that use global declarations to be very inelegant.  A much more pythonic approach would be to use a dictionary of values and have a single function for incrementing them.

Below is a very simple example to get you started:

```
dct = {
    'tick': 1,
    'week': 1,
    'month': 1,
    'year': 1
}

def increment(key):
    dct[key] += 1

increment('week')
print dct['week']
increment('tick')
print dct['tick']
```

Output:

```
2
2
```

Comment: Ok, so when do I have to include variables within the () when defining a function, and when don't I?

Comment: whilst correct and answering the literal question, this is not really encouraging good style in python

Comment: @Willman42 - The names inside the parenthesis are a function's parameters.  When you pass arguments to a function, they will be assigned to the parameter names.  You would do this when the behavior of your function needs to change in response to specific values.  The function you have now however does not require this.  It's one purpose is to increment the global names `week` and `tick`.  So, we remove the arguments because it does not need them

Comment: @wim - I agree that this isn't the cleanest code, but it looks as if the OP is doing an assignment.  I didn't want to move beyond his experience level.  In good time, I'm sure that he will learn many more pythonic ways of doing this.  I'll mention it though.

Comment: @iCodez - So I could actually write a single function to add 1 to each variable's value (week, tick, month, year), then just say tick(tick), tick(week), tick(month), and tick(year)?

Comment: @Willman42 - Not exactly.  Names (commonly called variables) are just that: names for an object.  When you pass them to a function, the value of the name is passed, not the name itself.  You could however make a dictionary such as `{'week':1, 'tick':1, ...}` and then pass the key as a string.  Give me a second and I'll include a demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

This is about scope.

```
# here you are setting your variables, there scope is essentially global
tick = 1
week = 1
month = 1
year = 1

# we enter the function definition
def new_week(week, tick):
# you passed in your variables, and increment them
# however, they are only changed within the local scope of this function
# and since you didn't RETURN them as shown below, you are leaving the
# global variables from above, unchanged
week = week + 1
tick = tick + 1
if tick == 4:
    new_month()
    tick = 1

# when you print them out below, you are printing the unchanged globally scoped variables
new_week(week, tick)
print week, tick 
new_week(week, tick)
print week, tick
```

In order to get the desired result you would do:

```
tick = 1
week = 1
month = 1
year = 1

def new_week(week, tick):
    week += 1
    tick += 1
    if tick == 4:
        new_month()
        tick = 1
    return (week, tick)  #### return the variables

>>> week, tick = new_week(week, tick) ### capture the returned variables
>>> print week, tick
(2, 2)
```

Both `tick` and `week` will continue to increment each time you call `new_week`. Obviously, `tick` will reset once it reaches four. If you wanted to store the variables in a `list` or `dict`, then you could do the following:

Using a `dict`:

```
vars = {'tick': 1, 'week': 1, 'month': 1, 'year': 1}
```

This now changes how your function can handle the data:

```
    def new_week(lst=None):
        if lst:
            for key in lst:
                vars[key] += 1
            if vars['tick'] == 4:
                new_month()
                vars['tick'] = 1

>>> new_week(['week', 'tick'])
>>> print vars['week'], vars['tick']
2 2
```

Read about scope here:

https://www.inkling.com/read/learning-python-mark-lutz-4th/chapter-17/python-scope-basics

http://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php

Comment: It is also probably preferable not to use 'exactly' the same argument names in your function def as the names of the actual variables you are passing in, to avoid confusion mainly.

Comment: I see in the links that global variables are not good practice... But how would I otherwise store the value for 'week', as I want it to keep accruing and not reset like 'tick' does?

Comment: In my answer above, week does continue to accrue if you keep calling the new_week function, tick would too, if you weren't explicitly resetting it.

Comment: Edited to include your tick reset

Answer (score 1):

First, `week = week + 1` just rebinds the (local) name `week` to a new value; it does not affect the variable in the calling scope. However, since `int`s are immutable, even `week+=1` would not affect the calling scope; it would still just update the function-local `week` variable.

One option is to use a `dict` instead of individual variables. Since a `dict` is a mutable object, you can pass the reference to the `dict` as an argument, and changes to that object will be visible in the calling scope.

```
times = { 'tick': 1, 'week': 1, 'month': 1, 'year': 1}

def new_week(t):
   t['week'] += 1
   t['tick'] += 1
   if t['tick'] == 4:
       new_month(t)
       t['tick'] = 1

new_week(times)
```